# Can I forward issues from one SonarQube instance to another?

Tags: sonarqube

I have a plug-in that I really like that isn't supported in the latest LTS release of SonarQube. So I want to host an older version of SonarQube to use this plug-in to find issues, and then forward those issues to the newer version of SonarQube.

Is this possible?

Comment: Between SonarQube versions there could be many differences in the database structure. The most obvious solution is to analyze twice on both instances.You could also help the community to fix the plugin but since the latest LTS version is SonarQube 5.6.6 it must be a rather old plugin. Without any knowledge of the specific plugin it is impossible to say how to solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not possible to transfer Issues from one SonarQube instance to another.

As Jeroien Heier pointed out in a comment, the most reliable and elegant solution to your problem would be to have the plugin compatibility fixed.

Comment: Thanks. The developers are working on fixing the plugin for the latest version. However, that doesn't solve my immediate problem and who knows how long it will take to get it working again. I guess I'll just have to use something else.